# To split strings using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to split strings like the following one:

```
10004, 10005,     0,'1 ',2,2,1, 0.00000E+0, 0.00000E+0, 2, 'ALCAZAR,NMRD     ',1, 129,1.0000
```

I would like to get `"ALCAZAR,NMRD     "` as a single word. Obviously, if I use `","` as splitter in `str.split()`, this word will be splited into two strings. I was thinking about replacing `","`  within this word with space, then use `","` as splitter to split the whole line. But `str.replace()` does not give me the specified position to start or end. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue or problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like CSV. Have you tried the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example string, you can use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

st="""\
10004, 10005, 0,'1 ',2,2,1, 0.00000E+0, 0.00000E+0, 2, 'ALCAZAR,NMRD ',1, 129,1.0000"""

kwargs={'skipinitialspace':True, 'quotechar':"'"}

for e in csv.reader(st.splitlines(), **kwargs):
    print e
```

Prints:

```
['10004', '10005', '0', '1 ', '2', '2', '1', '0.00000E+0', '0.00000E+0', '2', 
'ALCAZAR,NMRD ', '1', '129', '1.0000']
```

If you want to rid yourself of the trailing whitespace on each element (such as `'ALCAZAR,NMRD '` -> `'ALCAZAR,NMRD'`):

```
for e in csv.reader(st.splitlines(), **kwargs):
    e=[x.strip() for x in e]
    # ... process the split list of elements from a line of csv...
```

Comment: Drewk, thanks a lot! the clue you offered is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the comma from the the string, you can use `string.translate()`...

```
my_string = "ALCAZAR,NMRD"
my_string.translate(None, ',')
```

[Read more about translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

---

Edit:  You could also you use `string.replace()` but I think `string.translate()` is faster.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem because your example uses the string *after* it has been extracted from the full line above. What would you recommend to handle the question as posed?

Answer (score -1):

Just use a regex :

```
import re
target = """10004, 10005, 0,'1 ',2,2,1, 0.00000E+0, 0.00000E+0, 2, 'ALCAZAR,NMRD ',1, 129,1.0000"""

exp = re.compile(r'(['\"][A-Za-z ]+,[\A-Za-z ]+['\"])|\'*([0-9\.E\+\-]+)')
exp.findall(target)
```

Returns [('', '10004'), ('', '10005'), ('', '0'), ('', '1'), ('', '2'), ('', '2'), ('', '1'), ('', '0.00000E+0'), ('', '0.00000E+0'), ('', '2'), ("'ALCAZAR,NMRD '", ''), ('', '1'), ('', '129'), ('', '1.0000')]
 then do what you would like to the matches.